# Fade in multiple images in secquence once they have loaded

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein

What I am trying to achieve is a grid of images (10x10) that firstly load after the rest of the page has finished loading, and secondly fade in 1 after another

i.e.
(represents only one line)

```
----------
+---------
++--------
+++-------
++++------
```

etc...
What I have so far is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var loadingImage = false;
function LoadImage(imageName,imageFile)
{
  if ((!document.images) || loadingImage) return;
  loadingImage = true;
  if (document.images[imageName].src.indexOf(imageFile)<0)
  {
    document.images[imageName].src = imageFile;
  }
  loadingImage = false;
}
LoadImage('0','images/0.jpg');
</script>
```

With this image tag

```
<img class="fade" name="0" onLoad="LoadImage('1','images/1.jpg')" />
```

This gives me half the solution in as much as it loads all the images in sequentially, but I cant seem to add a fade to these images. The images are set up in an UL with 10 pictures in each LI, and 10 LI's in total = 100 images.

How can I fade these in?
Also is there a way to print out all the images in a loop insted of having them manually written in, so the user doesnt have to go through and make sure every image tag is correctly named? (ive already got a batch image renamer)

I found **[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746141/multiple-fadein-animations-in-jquery)** which is similar to what I need, but I couldnt work out how to get it to load the way I want.
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Instead of what you have, you can do this, keep the markup simple:

```
<img class="fade" name="0" src="images/1.jpg" />
```

Then in your CSS just have them hidden initially:

```
.fade { display: none; }
```

Then on page load all the script you need to show them sequentially is this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".fade").each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(400*i).fadeIn();
  });
});
```

`window.onload` as opposed to `document.ready` waits until all images are loaded as well, so just use that event for your [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) code.  The *default* duration of any animation is 400ms, and in a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop `i` is the index (0-based) of the element, so the first image fades in instantly (once all are loaded), the second is delayed 400ms (via [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)), so it fades when the first is done, the third after that, etc.  If you want to fade slower, say 1 second each, just pass that to both functions, like this:

```
$(this).delay(1000*i).fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: ok that makes sense, i did think of doing it that way before posting on here but i was unsure of how to cause the delay.
I'll give it a go now and see how it goes.
cheers (Y)